# Optaplanner add computerroom restriction

Tags: java, constraints, optaplanner

it's my first post here and I'm posting for my team of learning Java programmer for an school project. So we aren't good programmer.
how can I add a constraint to make the Optaplanner move the lectures into a specific room type.
For example I want to move the lecture "Programming" into a computerroom and the lecture "Math" in a normal room. But with my constraint it declares the hard constraints but doesn't move the lectures in their room. This should be a negative constraint. So the negative score for this hard constraint is shown, but it still won't be resolved/moved.

Here's the constraint:

```
rule "computerroom"
    when
       $room : Room($computerroom : computerroom)
       $course : Course(computerroom == $computerroom)
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
end
```

We added a new variable to the class Room, that look like:

```
package org.optaplanner.examples.curriculumcourse.domain;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamAlias;
import org.optaplanner.examples.common.domain.AbstractPersistable;

@XStreamAlias("Room")
public class Room extends AbstractPersistable {

    private String code;
    private int capacity;
    private boolean computerroom;

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public boolean getComputerroom() {
        return computerroom;
    }

    public void setComputerroom(boolean computerroom) {
        this.computerroom = computerroom;
    }

    public int getCapacity() {
        return capacity;
    }

    public void setCapacity(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return code;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return code + " {C" + capacity + "}";
    }

}
```

So have u got an advise for us?

Another little thing: the Optaplanner gets a lot of data to work with: 
How can we increase the maximun seconds spend for resolving? Because we tried other values over 1152 but it does't work. 
It's only a little question, the constraint is more important, but we would be happy to get the program running!

Greets 
SEP2014

Answer (score 1):

That score rule isn't checking anything that is "planning variable" (= a variable that changes during solving). So it's static, it can never have a different score than with what it starts out with.

Consider this instead:

```
rule "computerroom"
  when
    // If there's a room which has no computer
    $r : Room(hasComputer == false)
    // And we're putting a course which needs a computer in that room
    $course : Course(needsComputer == true, room == $r)
  then
    scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
end
```

The important thing here is **`Course(..., room == $r)`**. That **`room`** is a planning variable: it changes during planning.

Note: this one doesn't punish courses that don't need a computer if they use a computer room (but that's easily changed).

Same rule, but written shorter and more efficiently:

```
rule "computerroom"
  when
    $course : Course(needsComputer == true, room != null, room.hasComputer == false)
  then
    scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
end
```