# Optaplanner: Extend vehiclerouting example to include secure transport

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I am want to add a simple boolean value to each vehicle that indicates if the vehicle is secure, then for each customer a similar boolean to indicate that the customer requires a secure vehicle.

I have got as far as working out I need to:

- extend the domain objects for Vehicle and Customer to reflect these.
- extend the input XML to have at least one secure Vehicle and one Customer requiring a secure collection.
- extend the vehicleRoutingScoreRules.drl to add a new rule "secure" with a hard constraint.

This is a little pathetic - but I am pushed for time and the drools manual is massive and I cannot figure out the syntax for what I think is a simple rule. Could some kind soul give me a starter here please.

Comment: More research and I think its the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25787865/optaplanner-add-computerroom-restriction - so i may be able to close my own question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working!

I have done the following:

- extend the domain objects for Vehicle and Customer to reflect these.

  ```
  //Vehicle.java
  protected boolean secure;
  public boolean isSecure() {return secure;}
  public void setSecure(boolean secure) {this.secure = secure;}

  //Customer.java
  protected boolean needsSecure;
  public boolean isNeedsSecure() {return needsSecure;}
  public void setNeedsSecure(boolean needsSecure) {this.needsSecure = needsSecure;}
  ```
- extend the input XML to have at least one secure Vehicle and one Customer requiring a secure collection.

  ```
  //cvrptw-25customers-secure.xml - cloned from cvrptw-25customers.xml
  <VrpVehicle id="56">
    <id>24</id>
    <capacity>200</capacity>
    <depot class="VrpTimeWindowedDepot" reference="30"/>
    <secure>true</secure>
  </VrpVehicle>

  <VrpTimeWindowedCustomer id="58">
   <id>1</id>
   <location reference="4"/>
   <demand>10</demand>
   <readyTime>912000</readyTime>
   <dueTime>967000</dueTime>
   <serviceDuration>90000</serviceDuration>
   <needsSecure>true</needsSecure>
  </VrpTimeWindowedCustomer>
  ```
- extend the vehicleRoutingScoreRules.drl to add a new rule "secure" with a hard constraint.

  ```
  rule "securePackage"
    when
      $customer : Customer(needsSecure == true, vehicle != null, vehicle.isSecure == false)
    then
      scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
  end
  ```

And it all works! With 3 "secure" customers with a total need = the total secure vehicle capacity I can see that one vehicle (the secure one) does all 3 pickups and is full.